# Invalid SDK settings. Configure app.server.parent.dir property in build.xxx.properties to point to Liferay home

Tags: liferay

I have the following directory structure
[image]

The circled directories are the paths of the liferay tomcat server and the sdk respectively.

and I have the file build.osama.properties with the following settings :

`app.server.parent.dir=D:\sources\lr_bundles\liferay_tomcat\liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3
app.server.tomcat.dir=${app.server.parent.dir}/tomcat-8.0.32`

and when I try to create a liferay plugin project it keeps saying :

[image]

I am using LR 7 ga3 with tomcat 8 and sdk 7 ga3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I'd reinstall the Liferay one more time with brief step-by-step instruction.

In a few words, you should install:

1. Database (if you want to use custom one)
2. Liferay Portal
3. Liferay IDE
4. Plugins SDK.

In the `plugins SDK` folder you should copy `build.properties` file, and change the copied build.propertis file name to build.osama.properties. (check this step one more time, may be your profile is named as **O**sama instead of **o**sama). Then you should open newly created build.osama.properties file and uncomment following lines:

```
app.server.type=tomcat
app.server.parent.dir=${sdk.dir}/../bundles
app.server.tomcat.dir=${app.server.parent.dir}/tomcat-7.0.42
app.server.tomcat.deploy.dir=${app.server.tomcat.dir}/webapps
app.server.tomcat.lib.global.dir=${app.server.tomcat.dir}/lib/ext
app.server.tomcat.portal.dir=${app.server.tomcat.dir}/webapps/ROOT
```

Make sure that app.server.type and app.server.dir properties should be correct.

Comment: It needs to me to write full path to the subdirectory
`app.server.parent.dir=${sdk.dir}/../bundles/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga5` - after that it works.

Answer (score 4):

Try with the slash using the *NIX way, or at least, double the '\', as it may be understood as an escape character.

```
app.server.parent.dir=D:/sources/lr_bundles/liferay_tomcat/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3
```

or

```
app.server.parent.dir=D:\\sources\\lr_bundles\\liferay_tomcat\\liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3
```

and see if it helps.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to combine previous answers ('/' instead of Windows' default '\') AND move liferay portal directory to C:/ (and point build.Username.Properties file to this directory).